# Confirm Delete works in Chrome, doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, laravel, firefox

I have this bit of JavaScript in my web application:

```
<script>

document.getElementById("revDel").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {

if (confirm("Confirm delete!")) {

}

else {

event.preventDefault();
}

}

</script>
```

It works fine in Chrome & IE; when a user attempts to delete a particular record, a prompt pops up and if they select "OK" the record gets deleted but if they click on "Cancel" the delete action is halted.

Unfortunately this doesn't work on Firefox; when the user clicks on delete, whatever option they click on, the record gets deleted either way.

Has anyone encountered this before and how did you go about solving it?

Comment: Try using document.getElementById("revDel").onclick = function(event) {myFunction(event)};   and function myFunction(event). I.e. pass event to the event handlers.

Comment: I use the confirm function enough to know that it works in many browser including Firefox.  You should place a breakpoint and step trough your code using firebug or something.

Comment: Or even better, don't use `confirm` or `alert`. Ever. People will hate you for even thinking about it. They both hijack the tab/window completely. Use a modal dialogue instead. Only legit use is for making sure people *really* want to leave your page if they have unsaved changes, and even that gets annoying.

Comment: Other than the obvious error (`event` is `undefined` and trying to call a method on it will `throw`), your code seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are not passing the *event* parameter to your callback function.

When your `.onclick` event fires it creates an *event object* which can then, optionally, be passed to your callback function like so:

```
document.getElementById("revDel").onclick = function(e) {myFunction(e)};
    function myFunction(e) {
        if (confirm("Confirm delete!")) {...}
        else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Where `e` is the event object thus containing the `preventDefault()` method.

All you need to do is pass the event object as a parameter to your callback function.

Comment: Thanks Sam Gomena and epascarello. This worked like a charm. Credits to @Dzmitry Kushnarou who caught the error first!

Answer (score -1):

Try to `return false` and not `event.preventDefault();`.

Comment: I wonder why this was downvoted. I think it’s VERY possible that global event is the culprit. return false or passing event to the callback via function parameters should fix that.

Comment: `event` isn't even defined, meaning its an error. And the function is an *event handler*, there's nothing waiting for a return value, so what difference could that make? Random guesses are not answers.

Comment: @JaredSmith window.event IS defined in IE (and perhaps Chrome?), it’s a non-standard Microsoft extension.

Comment: @DzmitryKushnarou not in chrome, so not likely to be the culprit here. But thanks for the tip, I didn't know that about IE. I removed the offending line and ran the OP's code in FF, worked fine.

Comment: @JaredSmith Chrome seems to have it. Try running document.onclick = function() {console.log(window.event);} in Chrome console in clicking in any place of the document, you’ll see MouseEvents being logged. So, this question seems a correct solution.

Comment: @DzmitryKushnarou not my install of chrome, typing `window.event` into the console yields `undefined`. Chrome 56.

Comment: @JaredSmith It’s supposed to be ``undefined`` outside of an actual event handler: it’s undefined because no event is occuring when you’re testing. That’s why I’ve given an example with ``onclick``.

Comment: @DzmitryKushnarou still `undefined` using your example, chrome 56.

Comment: @JaredSmith @DzmitryKushnarou i think is better use `return false` in this case. Less code and more efficient..

Comment: Well with return false you would need to make two changes to the OPs code... simply just replacing return false in it now would not work. You might want to show the OP how to make the fix.